# <xsl:copy-of copying the namespace present in the root node . How to avoid this?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I am trying to copy all the nodes present below the current node using `<xsl:copy-of select="." />` and it is copying the namespace present in the root node also.
 How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

If the namespaces are unwanted, then in XSLT 2.0 you can use `<xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/>`. Note however that this will only get rid of unused namespace nodes; it will not change the namespace of any element or attribute. If you want the elements or attributes in your copy to be in a different namespace from the original, then you need to do a recursive shallow copy, along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="new-namespace">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```